# PHP: convert date with DateTime Class

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

I've this date from PayPal IPN

```
payment_date = 20:12:59 Jan 13, 2009 PST
```

How i can convert in `Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z` ?

I did try with

```
$date = new DateTime($_POST['payment_date']);
$payment_date = $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
```

But in my DB I obtain only `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`

Thank you

Comment: Try [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and explicitly specify the date format you expect.

Comment: @DoobyInc: OP already knows how to change format, he is just asking why it doesn't work, when it should.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DateTime should be able to parse this format:

```
$str = '20:12:59 Jan 13, 2009 PST';    
$date = new DateTime($str);
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimezone('UTC'));
$payment_date = $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
echo $payment_date;
```

[Output](https://eval.in/64529):

```
2009-01-13T20:12:59Z
```

This should work as expected. Your `$_POST['payment_date']` variable may contain some extra characters at the beginning or end. You can try `trim()` on the `$_POST` variable to make sure there aren't any whitespace in the beginning or end.

Comment: Perfect ;) Now i need only to convert from PST to UTC, but no problem in that. Thank you very much